# How can I figure out when I installed a package using apt-get in Debian Linux?

Tags: linux, apt-get

I went to install [penguinspuzzle](http://penguinspuzzle.appspot.com/) today, and got the following message:

```
penguinspuzzle is already the newest version.
```

How can I figure out when it was installed using apt-get?

Answer (score 1):

From the file `/var/log/dpkg.log` most likely. Apt-get runs dpkg(1) under the hood and dpkg logs most of its actions to that file.